# Is there a way to get just one element from array that is returned as a function?

Tags: php

Say I have a function/method that returns an array, let's call it ArrayReturner().  But I only want the first element, [0].  Right now I'm doing something like...

```
$arrayReturned = ArrayReturner();
$varIWant = $arrayReturned[0];
```

Is there a way to do that in one line without the need for the temporary $arrayReturned array?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$arrayReturned = reset(ArrayReturner());
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work.  I code in strict and it gave the error "Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference", and the value assigned to $varIWant is something else... I'm not even sure where the number came from, but it's not the correct value.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed you can wrap the array in parentheses: `$arrayReturned = reset((ArrayReturner()));` This way it won't be passing a function by reference, just the value. This will conform to strict standards.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on PHP's version you use.

If you're using PHP < 5.4, then you cannot get that, like `ArrayReturner()[0]`. That's only possible in PHP >= 5.4.

If you want your code to be portable, that would work with old and new versions, then you'd better stick with that code:

```
$arrayReturned = ArrayReturner();
$varIWant = $arrayReturned[0];
```

Comment: Damn, I'm still running 5.3.27.  I'm not worried about portableness.  It's not worth upgrading just for this little feature, but I guess it's good to know.